# How to achieve that each node from the cluster accepts message from the Google pub/sub topic?

Tags: java, spring-cloud, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-gcp

I have cluster application which listen messages from tge subscription

So I have 1 topic and 1 subsctiption. Following schema works as load balancer so each node in the cluster accepts unique messages. like this

producer produces `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`

Lets say cluster contains 2 nodes. The possible situatiobs is `node_1` accepts `A` and `D` but `node_2` accepts `B`, `C` abd `E`

If I know how many nodes in the cluster I can create subscription for each node. It will allow to listen each message on the each cluster's node. But what if I node count is differs from time to time?(it might increase or decrease). How could I achieve accepting each message from the publisher on each node from the cluster?

Comment: If you have multiple instances of an application all pulling messages from one single subscription then, in normal circumstances, messages will be distributed across all your instances.

Comment: I mentioned it in the topic. But it is not my aim.

Comment: Does creating programmatically a subscription when your application starts up a suitable solution (one application = one subscription)?

Comment: @norbjd It looks like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, you would need to use SDK to create subscription from the client on the fly and remove the subscription once the client goes offline.

Don't think there is any other better way than this as the number of clients could go up or down.